# VBA Group and insert summary line

Tags: vba, excel

First: I apologize, as I've spent very little time with VBA. I have data something like this:

> Amount | Category 
>     2.00 | cat1 
>     4.00 | cat1 
>     3.00 | cat2 
>     5.00 | cat3

I'd like to have it end up like:

> Amount | Category 
>     2.00 | cat1 
>     4.00 | cat1 
>     Total: 6.00 | cat1 
>     3.00 | cat2 
>     Total: 3.00 | cat2 
>     5.00 | cat3 
>     Total: 5.00 | cat3

The code I found to insert a row was:

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue() 
Dim lRow As Long 
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 
    If Cells(lRow, "B") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "B") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert 
Next lRow 
End Sub
```

That works great, but I'm not sure how to do anything with the row that was created. Help? Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know about that, didn't even know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't worked much with VBA then any easy way to start getting aquainted with some of the structure is to record a macro of the steps you want to perform and look at the resulting code.

Keep in mind that the macro record goes step by step and therefore records sum ugly stuff such as screen shifts. As the recorded macros do not have error traps and I have never seen an instance of a recorded macro creating a loop.

Keep in mind your code assumes that the data always starts in A1 of the current sheet.

You need to add a little code to get what you are looking for. I would switch your code up to be:

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim cRow As Long
 Dim sSum As Long
 Dim formula As String
 'Stops screen updating and improves run times
 Application.ScreenUpdate = False
 'Start at row 3 because row 1 is a header so row 2 is first line of data
 cRow = 3
 'sSum is the start of Sum. The first row you might sum is 2.
 sSum = 2
 'Because of the sums easier to step down instead of up
 'Add 2 to last row to allow for the last sum
 lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 2
 Do Until cRow = lRow
     If Cells(cRow, "B") <> Cells(cRow - 1, "B") Then
          Rows(cRow).EntireRow.Insert
          Cells(cRow, "A").Select
          'Insert the formula
          ActiveCell.formula = "=""Total: """ & "& SUM(A" & sSum & ":A" & cRow - 1 & ")"
          'Update column B
          Cells(cRow, "B").Value = Cells(cRow - 1, "B")
          'Increase the next sum to the row after the one you just added.
          sSum = cRow + 1
          'Increase the last row count
          lRow = lRow + 1
          'Check to make sure you are not at the bottom of the workbook
          If cRow = 65536 Then
               cRow = lRow
          Else
               cRow = cRow + 2
          End If
     Else
          'Increment if the rows are the same in column B
          'Check if you are at the bottom of the workbook
          If cRow = 65536 Then
               cRow = lRow
          Else
               cRow = cRow + 1
          End If
     End If
 Loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I added some comments to try and explain what is going on.

Comment: This does do what I want, but the "Subtotal" feature in Excel does it faster :-) Thanks for taking the time to write that up, and for commenting!